# value fed by Pipeline versus Argument

Tags: powershell

I have a simple Powershell script that I want to accept string values via Pipeline/Argument or plain just run the script.

```
#myscript
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,ValueFromPipeline)][string[]]$dnshostname
)

Begin {

    If(-Not $dnshostname){
        Write-Host "I AM HERE"
        $raw = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property *
        $raw | ForEach {
            If (Test-Connection -Delay 15 -ComputerName $_.IPv4Address -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
                $dnshostname += $_.DNSHostname
            }
        }
    }
}

Process {
...
...
}
```

When I run this script like this: **"myserver" | ./myscript.ps1**

I get the "I AM HERE" message which means the $dnshostname variable is empty, but wasn't it fed from the pipeline?

If I run the same script as: **./myscript.ps1 -dnshostname "myserver"**, I do not get the "I AM HERE" message which mean it correctly determined that the $dnshostname variable is not empty.

I am sure I am missing something very fundamental here. May i get some guidance pretty please as to why the value passed via the pipeline triggers my IF statement?
Thank you!

Comment: You will need a `Process` block after your `Begin` block. That's where the elements passed by the pipeline get processed.  ;-)  The `Begin` block is actually meant to prepare the environment to process everything  ... set up variables create helper functions and so on ...

Comment: Thanks Olaf. Sorry, I did not include my Process block. I did not think it was relevant to the behavior I am trying to resolve. I'll edit my code block.

Comment: My apologies, I have misread your response. SO the pipeline variable never makes it to Begin block! Aha! Thank you very much. Seems like I have to initialize my $dnshostname variable in the Process block then. Now, How can I set your response as the answer to my question?

Comment: No need to award me for that. I'm glad it helped you.